# Can't export report to .xls anymore in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, report, xls, excel-2016, ms-access-2016

I usually right click -> export report as .xls to a directory but lately it hasn't worked, giving the error:

> Microsoft Access can't complete the Output operation.
>
> The visual basic code you entered contains a syntax error or the
> Output procedures are not available.
>
> Make sure there isn't a syntax error in your code. if the syntax is
> correct, run Setup to reinstall Microsoft Access. If you want to
> preserve your security or custom settings, back up the Microsoft
> Access workgroup information file. For information on backing up
> files, search the Microsoft Windows Help index for 'backing up files'.

(Error code 2587)

This happens no matter what I try to export. Is there a workaround or fix?

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this one today too, with the same symptoms and error message. Completely uninstalling and reinstalling Office+Access resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Have also run into this problem today.  The following article

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/ms-access-cant-complete-the-output-operation/882ee01c-3e12-45df-8c22-ed73aa043c48?page=2

suggests it's specific to build 15225.20292

and it should be fixed if you run MS Updates and get the latest build installed which is 15330.20204

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-s-new-in-microsoft-365-95c8d81d-08ba-42c1-914f-bca4603e1426?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.  Updating Access to build 15330.20264 was the key.

Comment: Before posting an answer, make sure the solution hasn't already been posted by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Cross posted...

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/ms-access-cant-complete-the-output-operation/882ee01c-3e12-45df-8c22-ed73aa043c48?page=14

I'm surprised it has not been mentioned before BUT....

Regardless of which updates etc you install you will STILL experience the "Can't complete the output operation" when attempting to output to Excel if your macro settings are set to 'Disable all macros without notification' OR 'Disable all macros except digitally signed macros'.

This occurs I believe because the export to Excel process involves a macro or code in the access utility.accda module which is now untrusted.

You can change your macro settings in the Trust Center ( for 2016 - File, Options, Trust Center, Trust Center Settings, Macro Settings) Depending on your use case you can set to Enable all macros (which is not recommended) or Disable all macros WITH notification. This setting allows you to decide each time if you want to run the macro or not.

The other issue I've seen is if you are not seeing all the export options in the ribbon you need to change a setting to display full menus. (File, Options, Current Database) scroll down to Ribbon and Toolbar options and ensure the tickbox is checked beside Allow Full Menus

Close Access, restart and your problem should now be resolved.

Note that an Access Security Notice window will pop when you try export to Excel, you should click Open to allow the export to proceed.